# PN sequence generator using linear feedback shift register in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, shift-register, pn-sequence

I got a code for PN sequence generator using linear feedback shift register in VHDL.

I am using `1010` as a initial seed but in the output all the four PN sequences are `1`.

What changes I should do to obtain different PN sequences?

I'm using Xilinx ISE 10.1.  This is the code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity pnsmall_1 is
  Port (
    clock           : in  STD_LOGIC;                    -- synchronous clock input
    init            : in  STD_LOGIC_vector (3 downto 0);    -- the seed
    pn1,pn2,pn3,pn4 : out STD_LOGIC);                   -- PN sequence
end pnsmall_1;

architecture Behavioral of pnsmall_1 is
  component dp
    port (
      clk,clr,pst,d : in  std_logic;
      q             : out std_logic
    );
  end component;

  component exor
    port (
      a,b : in  std_logic;
      z   : out std_logic
    );
  end component;

  signal q0          : std_logic;   -- 1st stage out
  signal q1          : std_logic;   -- 2nd stage out
  signal q2          : std_logic;   -- 3th stage out
  signal q3          : std_logic;   -- 4th stage out
  signal x           : std_logic;   -- 1st stage input, the feedback
  signal qout        : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin
  s0: dp port map(
        clk => clock,
        clr => '0',
        pst => init(0),
        d   => x,
        q   => q0
        );
  s1: dp port map(
        clk => clock,
        clr => '0',
        pst => init(1),
        d   => q0,
        q   => q1
        );
  s2: dp port map(
        clk => clock,
        clr => '0',
        pst => init(2),
        d   => q1,
        q   => q2
        );
  s3: dp port map(
        clk => clock,
        clr => '0',
        pst => init(3),
        d   => q2,
        q   => q3
        );

  xx: exor port map(q0,q3,x);

  process(clock)
  begin
    qout(0)<=q3;
    if(clock'event and clock='1') then
      for i in 0 to 6 loop
        qout(i+1)<=qout(i);
      end loop;

      pn1<=qout(1);
      pn2<=qout(3);
      pn3<=qout(5);
      pn4<=qout(7);
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

the code for dp is below

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

library UNISIM; 
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

-- Code for D FlipFlop with synchronous clear and preset.
entity dp is
   Port (
       clk : in STD_LOGIC; -- synchronous clock
       clr : in STD_LOGIC; -- clear
       pst : in STD_LOGIC; -- preset
       d   : in STD_LOGIC; -- data input
       q   : out STD_LOGIC -- data output
       );
end dp;

architecture Behavioral of dp is
begin
    process(clk,pst,clr) 
      begin 
        if(pst='1')then 
            q<='1';
          elsif(clr='1')then
            q<='0'; 
          elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then 
            q<=d;
        end if;
    end process; 
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Indent, and comment your code. Please prefer _named instantiation_ instead of _positional instantiation_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to all of the issues that Paebbels raises, your immediate problem is that you seem to have misunderstood the function of the `pst` input of your `dp` module.

Since you don't show the code for `dp`, I'm making a lot of assumptions, but if this is a standard D flip-flop module, the `clr` (clear) and `pst` (preset) inputs will override the `d` input whenever they are asserted.

Therefore, two of your `dp` modules are being forced to '1' at all times by the `init` vector, and the rest become '1' shortly afterward because of your logic.

Comment: I have attached(edited the question) and added the code of dp.And yes it stands for D flip-flop.

Answer (score 1):

Xilinx application note 052 describes how to implement such circuits => [XAPP052](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf)

Besides that, here are some hints and questions for your code:

- Your Xilinx ISE 10.1 is very outdated. It's from 2008 or so. Current (and last) version is 14.7 from 2013.
- Please use the `ieee.numeric_std` library instead of `ieee.std_logic_arith` and `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`
- You aren't using any Xilinx primitives, so you don't need to use `unisim`.
- Why are you using self instantiated flip flops (sd) on the one hand and a generic code description on the other hand?
- Why is your output double registered? Your process describes 13 flip flips. The output of a LFSR is normally registered by it-self.
- Why are you using odd indices in qout?
- Have you checked that your polynomial is a generator polynomial and that your init value is a generating element?

Comment: i'm using this for generating code for 4 cdma users. so i need odd indices. i want qout(0) qout(2) qout(4) qout(6) to be containing the outputs of 4 D flipflops.

Comment: Might it not be wise to use 4 independent PRNGs (pseudo random number generator) with a higher order polynomial (-> longer cycle type) and different orders? On per user.